# SSL Socket free and shutdown

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl, file-descriptor

For an `SSL` connection, what all can be done with a `FD` received from an accept call? Can it be reused?

What I want to know exactly want to know is this :

Once I accept a connection, I get the `FD`.
I create an SSL handle (`SSL*`) using `SSL_new`.
Add the `FD` to this handle using `SSL_set_fd`.
I do the handshake using `SSL_accept`.
Now at this point if I call `SSL_shutdown` on `SSL*`, will the `FD` be closed? What about SSL_free?

If the answer to the above question is no, then can I use the `FD` with another `SSL*`?

To explain what I want exactly, if we read some data from the connection `FD` using handle `SSL*`, then we free or shutdown `SSL*`, can we read the remaining data from `FD` using a new `SSL*`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056056/handling-ssl-shutdown-correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSL_shutdown only sends an close notify over the socket. If you want to reuse the socket afterwards as a plain socket you have to make sure, that the other side did also an SSL_shutdown. This information gives you the return code of your SSL_shutdown: if it is 1 the SSL connection is closed, if it is 0 you should call SSL_shutdown again so wait for the close notify from the peer. Please see the SSL_shutdown documentation for more information.

After this is done you can continue to use the socket as a plain socket. This what is done in SSL over FTP (ftps), e.g. with "AUTH TLS" the connection will be upgraded to SSL and with "CCC" it will be downgraded to plain text again.

SSL_free only frees the memory associated with the SSL object, it does not change anything on the socket nor does it send/receive any data.

Comment: Please read my latest edit. For that use, will SSL_free be best suited or should i try shutdown?

Comment: like I said: SSL_free only frees the memory (actually it decreases the reference counter on the SSL object and frees the memory if the counter gets 0) and does nothing with the socket itself. If you want to read the remaining data on the socket, e.g. downgrade the socket from SSL to plain, you have to use SSL_shutdown to send a close notify to the peer, so that it shuts the SSL session down.

Comment: What I want to do is pass the socket to some other class and read the remaining ssl data from there, from the same connection.

Comment: If you want to keep the SSL connection open you should not call SSL_shutdown, because this will end the SSL connection (but keep the underlying socket open). If you just give the SSL object to another class you should not call SSL_free either - because the SSL object is still needed in the other class. SSL_free should only be called once the SSL object is not needed anymore, e.g. after SSL_shutdown.

Comment: if I call SSL free on existing SSL*, take the FD, then create a new SSL* and add the FD to this SSL*, will it work?

Comment: No, because the information about the state of the SSL connection are inside the SSL structure and not the fd.

Comment: thought so. :) so i have to use the same SSL* which was used to do the handshake.. thanks.. if i create a new SSL*, can I do the SSL handshake again and expect things to work?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so, does that means that the read and write BIOs are not tightly coupled with the socket? (cf the man "SSL_free() also calls the free()ing procedures for indirectly affected items, if applicable: the buffering BIO, the read and write BIOs, [...]").

Comment: @Bacon: the SSL layer is not tightly coupled with the underlying socket, i.e. the SSL layer can be closed while the socket is kept open for non-SSL data or even a new SSL session. If this does not answer the question you have asked in your comment please ask a real question with enough context.

Comment: It does answer my question. Thanks!