# Handling SSL_shutdown correctly

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl

The OpenSSL documentation on `SSL_shutdown` states that:

> It is therefore recommended, to check the return value of `SSL_shutdown()` and call `SSL_shutdown()` again, if the bidirectional shutdown is not yet complete (return value of the first call is 0).

https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html

I have a code snippet below where I check for return value 0 from `SSL_shutdown` and call it again, which I have been using. My question is, is it okay to disregard the return value of `SSL_shutdown` on the second call or we should keep retrying `SSL_shutdown` until a 1 (bidirectional shutdown complete) is returned.

```
int r = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
//error handling here if r < 0 
if(!r)
{
    shutdown(fd,1);
    SSL_shutdown(ssl); //how should I handle return value and error handling here is it required?? 
}
SSL_free(ssl);
SSLMap.erase(fd);
shutdown(fd,2);
close(fd);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**`openssl`** is a bit of a dark art.

Firstly the page you referenced has HTML-ified the return values badly. Here's what the man-page *actually* says:

```
  RETURN VALUES

   The following return values can occur:

   0   The shutdown is not yet finished. Call SSL_shutdown() for a second
       time, if a bidirectional shutdown shall be performed.  The output
       of SSL_get_error(3) may be misleading, as an erroneous
       SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL may be flagged even though no error occurred.

   1   The shutdown was successfully completed. The "close notify" alert
       was sent and the peer's "close notify" alert was received.

   -1  The shutdown was not successful because a fatal error occurred
       either at the protocol level or a connection failure occurred. It
       can also occur if action is need to continue the operation for non-
       blocking BIOs.  Call SSL_get_error(3) with the return value ret to
       find out the reason.
```

If you have blocking BIOs, things are relatively simple. A 0 on the first call means you need to call `SSL_shutdown` again if you want a full bidirectional shutdown.  Basically it means that you sent a close_notify alert but haven't one back yet).  A 1 would mean you previously received a close_notify alert from the other peer, and you're totally done.  A -1 means an unrecoverable error.  On the second call (which you only do if you got a 0 back), then a bidirectional shutdown is initiated (i.e. now wait from the other side for them to send you their "close_notify" alert). Logic dictates you can't get a 0 back again (because it's a blocking BIO and will have completed the first step). A -1 indicates an error, and a 1 indicates completion success.

If you have non-blocking BIOs, the same "possibly 0 then 1" return values apply, save for the fact you need to go through the whole `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` and `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` rigmarole as well, i.e.:

```
   If the underlying BIO is non-blocking, SSL_shutdown() will also return
   when the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs of SSL_shutdown()
   to continue the handshake. In this case a call to SSL_get_error() with
   the return value of SSL_shutdown() will yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or
   SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE. The calling process then must repeat the call
   after taking appropriate action to satisfy the needs of SSL_shutdown().
   The action depends on the underlying BIO. When using a non-blocking
   socket, nothing is to be done, but select() can be used to check for
   the required condition. When using a buffering BIO, like a BIO pair,
   data must be written into or retrieved out of the BIO before being able
   to continue.
```

So you have two levels of repetition. You call `SSL_shutdown` the 'first' time but repeat if you get `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` after going around the `select()` loop in the normal way, and only count the 'first' `SSL_shutdown` as done if you get a non `SSL_ERROR_WANT_` error code (in which case it failed), or you get a `0` or `1` return. If you get a `1` return, you've done. If you get a `0` return, and you want a bidirectional shutdown, then you have to do the second call, on which again you will need to check for `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` and retry select; that should not return `1`, but may return 0 or an error.

Not simple.

Couple more notes from the [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_shutdown.html): after calling `SSL_shutdown` and getting a "0" back the first time, you could optionally then call `SSL_read` instead of `SSL_shutdown` (in case the peer is still sending you any data on that SSL socket), and, I guess, "hope" that they eventually send you a close message from their side, to flush the pipes.

Also if you're planning on closing the socket after shutdown completion "anyway" you could entirely skip the second call to `SSL_shutdown` (the "1" of the "0 then 1") and just go ahead and close the socket, the kernel should take care of discarding the "now ignored" close_notify alert that presumably they should be about to send...

Comment: Note that with TLS 1.3 you cannot skip the second `SSL_shutdown`, particularly when the traffic is purely local to remote. See for example https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7948