# SSL_shutdown returns -1 with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ infinitely long

Tags: c++, openssl, nonblocking

I cannot understand how to properly use SSL_Shutdown command in OpenSSL. Similar questions arisen several times in different places, but I couldn't find a solution which matches exactly my situation. I am using package libssl-dev 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15 (the latest for now) under Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

I am working with a small legacy C++ wrapper over the OpenSSL library with non-blocking IO for server and client sockets. The wrapper seems to work fine, except in the following test case (I'm not providing the code of the unit test itself, because it contains a lot of code not related to the problem):

1. Initialize a server socket with self-signed certificate
2. Connect to that socket. SSL handshake completes successfully, except that I'm ignoring X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT return of SSL_get_verify_result for now.
3. Successfully send/receive some data through the connection. This step is optional and it doesn't affect the problem which follows. I mention it only to show that the connection is really established and set into correct state.
4. Trying to shutdown SSL connection (server or client, doesn't matter which one) which leads to infinite wait on select.

All of the calls to SSL_read and SSL_write are synchronized, locking_callback is also set. After step 3 there are no other operations on sockets except shutting down on one of them.

In the code snippet below I omit all of the error processing and debugging code for clarity, none of the OpenSSL/POSIX calls fail (except cases where I left error processing in place). I also provide connect functions, in case this is important:

```
void OpenSslWrapper::ConnectToHost( ErrorCode& ec )
{
    ctx_ = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx_, NULL, config_.verify_locations.c_str());

    if (config_.use_standard_verify_locations)
    {
        SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx_);
    }

    bio_ = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx_);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio_, &ssl_);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl_, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    std::string hostname = config_.address + ":" + to_string(config_.port);
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio_, hostname.c_str());

    BIO_set_nbio(bio_, 1);

    int res = 0;
    while ((res = BIO_do_connect(bio_)) <= 0)
    {
        BIO_get_fd(bio_, &fd_);

        if (!BIO_should_retry(bio_))
        { /* Never happens */}

        WaitAfterError(res);
    }

    res = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl_);
    if (res != X509_V_OK && res != X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT)
    { /* Never happens */ } 

    SSL_set_mode(ssl_, SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl_, SSL_MODE_ACCEPT_MOVING_WRITE_BUFFER);
}

// config_.handle is a file descriptor which was got from
// accept function, stx_ is also set in advance
void OpenSslWrapper::ConnectAsServer( ErrorCode& ec )
{
    ssl_ = SSL_new(ctx_);

    int flags = fcntl(config_.handle, F_GETFL, 0);
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(config_.handle, F_SETFL, flags);

    SSL_set_fd(ssl_, config_.handle);

    while (true)
    {
        int res = SSL_accept(ssl_);
        if( res > 0) {break;}
        if( !WaitAfterError(res).isSucceded() )
        { /* never happens */ }
    }

    SSL_set_mode(ssl_, SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl_, SSL_MODE_ACCEPT_MOVING_WRITE_BUFFER);
}

// The trouble is here
void OpenSSLWrapper::Shutdown()
{
  // ...
  while (true)
  {
    int ret = SSL_shutdown(ssl_);
    if (ret > 0) {break;}
    else if (ret == 0) {continue;}
    else {WaitAfterError(ret);}
  }
  // ...
}

ErrorCode OpenSSLWrapper::WaitAfterError(int res)
{
  int err = SSL_get_error(ssl_, res);
  switch (ret)
  {
  case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
    WaitForFd(fd_, k_WaitRead);
    return ErrorCode::Success;
  case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
  case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
  case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
    WaitForFd(fd_, k_WaitWrite);
    return ErrorCode::Success;
  default:
    return ErrorCode::Fail;
  }
}
```

WaitForFd is just a simple wrapper over the select, which waits on a given socket infinitely long on a specified FD_SET for read or write.

When the client calls Shutdown, the first call to SSL_Shutdown returns 0. After the second call it returns -1 and SSL_get_error returns SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, but selecting on the file descriptor for reading never returns. If specify timeout on select, SSL_Shutdown will continue returning -1 and SSL_get_error continue returning SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. The loop never exits. After the first call to SSL_Shutdown the shutdown status is always SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN.

It doesn't matter if I close a server or a client: both have the same behavior.

There's also a strange situation when I connect to some external host. The first call to SSL_Shutdown returns 0, the second one -1 with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. Selecting on the socket finishes successfully, but when I call to SSL_Shutdown next time, I again got -1 with error SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL and errno=0. As I read in other places, it is not a big deal, although it still seems strange and maybe it is somehow related, so I mention it here.

**UPD.** I ported that same code for Windows, the behavior didn't change.

P.S. I am sorry for mistakes in my English, I'd be grateful if someone corrects my language.

Comment: A small nit probably not related to your problem: you should be doing more than `ctx_ = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());`. There are context options that should be tweaked, and you should be using [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). See, for example, [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056056/handling-ssl-shutdown-correctly