# OpenSSL error handling

Tags: c, error-handling, openssl

Is this the correct way to do error handling in OpenSSL?
And what is the difference between `SSL_get_error` and `ERR_get_error`?
The docs are quite vague in this regard.

```
int ssl_shutdown(SSL *ssl_connection)
{
    int rv, err;
    ERR_clear_error();
    rv = SSL_shutdown(ssl_connection);

    if (rv == 0)
        SSL_shutdown(ssl_connection);

    if (rv < 0)
    {
        err = SSL_get_error(ssl_connection, rv);

        if (err == SSL_ERROR_SSL)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", SSL_state_string(ssl_connection));

        return 1;
    }

    SSL_free(ssl_connection);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SSL_get_error](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_get_error.html):

> SSL_get_error() returns a result code (suitable for the C "switch"
> statement) for a preceding call to SSL_connect(), SSL_accept(),
> SSL_do_handshake(), SSL_read(), SSL_peek(), or SSL_write() on ssl. The
> value returned by that TLS/SSL I/O function must be passed to
> SSL_get_error() in parameter ret.

[ERR_get_error](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/ERR_get_error.html):

> ERR_get_error() returns the earliest error code from the thread's
> error queue and removes the entry. This function can be called
> repeatedly until there are no more error codes to return.

So the latter is for more general use and those shouldn't be used together, because:

> The current thread's error queue must be empty before the TLS/SSL I/O operation is attempted, or SSL_get_error() will not work reliably.

So you have to read all of the errors using ERR_get_error and handle them (or ignore them by removal as you did in your code sample with `ERR_clear_error`) and then perform the IO operation. Your approach seems to be correct, although I can't check all aspects of it by myself at the moment.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28056464/5922757) and [this post](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/issues/168) for more information.

EDIT: according to [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/network-security-with/059600270X/ch04.html) tutorial, BIO_ routines may generate an error and affect error queue:

> The third field is the name of the package that generated the error,
> such as **"BIO routines"** or "bignum routines".

Comment: It seems like it @Red. I edited my answer. Refer to [this website](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/network-security-with/059600270X/ch04s02.html) for more info.

Answer (score 10):

> And what is the difference between SSL_get_error and ERR_get_error?

There are two logical parts to OpenSSL. First is the SSL library, `libssl.a` (and `libssl.so`), and it includes the communication related stuff. Second is the cryptography library, `libcrypto.a` (and `libcrypto.so`), and it includes big numbers, configuration, input/output, etc.

`libssl.a` depends upon `libcrypto.a`, and its why the link command is ordered as `-lssl -lcrypto`.

You use `SSL_get_error` to retrieve most errors from the SSL portion library, and you use `ERR_get_error` to retrieve errors not in the SSL portion of the library.

---

> Is this the correct way to do error handling in OpenSSL?

The code you showed is closer to *"how do you shutdown a SSL socket"*. Ultimately, the gyrations control two cases. First is a half open connection, when the client shutdowns without sending the close notify message. The second is your program's behavior when sending the close notify message.

Its hard to answer "is it correct" because we don't know the behavior you want. If you don't care if the close notify is sent, then I believe you only need to call `SSL_shutdown` once, regardless of what the client does.

Comment: My intended behavior is to wait for close notify.
Is my usage of SSL_get_error and ERR_get_error correct?
I did not encounter an SSL_* equivalent of ERR_error_string, so I assumed SSL_state_string would yield the same functionality, but I'm not sure.