# Does BIO_reset calls close(socket_fd) internally? Or do we have close the socket file descriptor explicitly

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

My program got crashed when I call close(socket_fd) after BIO_reset function. Crash log shows invalid handle passed to close() function.

```
void close_ssl_stream(BIO *bio, int socket)
{
    BIO_flush(bio);
    BIO_reset(bio);
    BIO_free_all(bio);
    ERR_clear_error();
    ERR_free_strings();
    ERR_remove_state(0);
    printf("Closing socket fd: %d\n", socket);
    close(socket);
}
```

Program crashes at close(socket) line.

I have moved close(socket) line above BIO_reset function.

```
 {
        BIO_flush(bio);
        printf("Closing socket fd: %d\n", socket);
        close(socket);
        BIO_reset(bio);
        BIO_free_all(bio);
        ERR_clear_error();
        ERR_free_strings();
        ERR_remove_state(0);
    }
```

Now it crashes at BIO_reset(bio) line.
How to free the socket file descriptor in this program? Any suggestions to improve this code is also welcomed.

Comment: Your latter snippet looks a lot like the first, is there a mistake in it? Also, (the system call) `close()` shouldn't crash, regardless of what you pass it, it might return `EBADFD` though.

Comment: @ilkkachu . Yeah. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [BIO_Reset](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_reset)() does not close the underlying file descriptor. You don't need to call BIO_Reset in the code you have shown if all you do afterwards is to free/close the BIO.

BIO_free()/BIO_free_all() will close the underlying file descriptor if you have set the BIO_CLOSE flag on the BIO. Otherwise you have to close() the file descriptor yourself.

(Note that your ERR_clear_error and other ERR_ calls operate globally, you shouldn't perform these calls unless you never intend to use the SSL library again)

Answer (score 1):

As [nos said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44566044/10871073), it is correct that you don't need to do `BIO_Reset()` in your case, because you want to free the bio. But  that said, then why do you call the function `close_ssl_stream`? You should probably choose another name.

He mentions that you need to set the flag `BIO_CLOSE` to the object BIO if you want it to close the connection automatically when you call `BIO_free()`. To be more specific, you can set the flag at the moment you create the BIO object, like this:

```
if(!BIO_set_close(bio, BIO_CLOSE))
{
    // Print the error queue
    return -1;
}
```

**Notes for some functions you are using:**

```
ERR_free_strings();
```

This is deprecated since openSSL version 1.1.0.

```
void ERR_remove_state(unsigned long tid);
```

This is deprecated since openSSL version 1.0.0

Please consider that [ERR_clear_error](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/ERR_clear_error.html)  clears the current thread's error queue, and it is *not* true that you shouldn't perform this call: just remember to check/print the queue before removing it.

In this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980798/openssl-error-handling), you have some more info about handling the error queue.