# OpenSSL SSL_read Failure (error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib)

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, tcp, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL version 1.1.0f to encrypt the connection between my client and a relaying server for which I don't have any access. Some times the client's connection is getting terminated abruptly with the readLine failure on client side.

Here is the error code:

> readLine: readString returned -1 , Error Msg - error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib

I did search for the appropriate reasons for this kind of error code, everybody (Example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479376/openssl-ssl-accept-error-5) thread) says that there seems to be a problem with the Diffie-Hellman key exchange during the connection establishment. But The connection was going fine for few minutes(some times it may not even occur and it may occur very frequently once after 2 to 3 minutes of connection success) until it get terminated abruptly.

Here are some more errors from the logs that I have

> SSL_read failed with error - 5, bytes received -1, error string error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib, wsaError 0
>
> SSL Error - 5:error:FFFFFFFF:lib(255):func(4095):reason(4095)

Here is the socket read code from the SSL client

```
if ((isSecureMode() == true) && (lpSSL != NULL))
{
    bytesReceived = SSL_read(lpSSL, receiveBuf, bufferSize) ;

    if ((bytesReceived <= 0))
    {
        int sslErrorCode = lpSSL ? SSL_get_error(lpSSL, bytesReceived) : -1;

        char sslErrorString[MAX_ERROR_MSG_LEN] = {'\0'};

        ERR_error_string(sslErrorCode, sslErrorString);
        setLastError(sslErrorCode, std::string(sslErrorString));

        int wsaError = WSAGetLastError();

        if(isShutdownInitiated == false)
        {
            if (Logger)
            {
                Logger->log(LOG_WARNING, "receiveString - SSL_read failed with error - %d, bytes received %d, error string %s, wsaError %d", sslErrorCode, bytesReceived, std::string(sslErrorString), wsaError);
            }
                                                    // Always return -1 incase of failure
            bytesReceived = -1;
        } 
        else
        {
            if (Logger)
            {
                Logger->log(LOG_WARNING, "receiveString - Socket was Shutdown, SSL_read failed with error - %d, bytes received %d, error string %s , wsaError %d", sslErrorCode, bytesReceived, std::string(sslErrorString), wsaError);
            }
                                    
            setLastError(ERROR_ALREADY_SHUTDOWN);
            bytesReceived = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert in OpenSSL and I doubted that the problem may be with the server but there are no error messages that can prove it except for the above ones.

I did analyze a lot and spent weeks without any improvement.

**Update :**
Upon analyzing the error messages the error code SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL along with the wsa error_code 10054 says that the connection has been terminated by the remote party. The same error message is being written on server logs. That leads to the doubt for the connection being reset by the intermediate devices (may be routers that reside in between the client and the server) as per [this](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2003-01/0115.html) thread. I'm trying to analyze further and sort out the problem.

**Update 2:** I also found out that the problem happens some times that is only on some networks. It works perfectly fine on few networks.The above mentioned thread also tells the same.

**Update 3:** I had figured out one of the reasons for connection termination, The error 10054 was actually due to firewall and the network that has been resolved now.

Debugging the readline failure with error

> SSL_read failed with error - 5, bytes received -1, error string
> error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib, wsaError 0

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: DId you check your private key and certificate for consistenency using SSL_CTX_check_private_key() ? I doubt on your context object. Also what method you used for SSL_CTX?

Comment: I'm using TLSv1_2_client_method for SSL_CTX.

Comment: I'm not doing any SSL_CTX_check_private_key(). Going with the default cert store certificates and the server's certificate is signed by a trusted authority.

Comment: Which version of openSSL yo are using?

Comment: I'm using OpenSSL version 1.1.0f.

Comment: May be you can try using  SSLv23_client_method. Can understand TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 protocols. Look into https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_CTX_new(3)

Comment: *But The connection was going fine for few minutes(some times it may not even occur and it may occur very frequently once after 2 to 3 minutes of connection success) until it get terminated abruptly.*  That sounds like an intermediate device such as a firewall or NAT router timing out a connection without any traffic for its timeout interval.  How do you establish your TCP connection?  You might get better results if you enable TCP keepalive.

Comment: We have configured firewalls properly. The connection termination is random actually. It happens twice at the max for a 30 minutes of streaming. 60% of the times it may not even happen. The SO_KEEPALIVE is not set actually, will try with that.

Comment: Setting SO_KEEPALIVE did not solve the problem.

Comment: Could not figure out what is causing the problem "SSL_read failed with error - 5, bytes received -1, error string error:00000005:lib(0):func(0):DH lib, wsaError 0" yet.

Comment: Without a proper WSA error code for the above mentioned case it is really difficult to debug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return values of [`SSL_get_error`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_get_error(3)) should not be passed to [`ERR_error_string`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:ERR_error_string(3)).  The value 5 in `sslErrorCode` is probably `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.

You should loop over the local threads error queue with `ERR_get_error` to find the reason for the failure, and you also should empty the error queue before calling `SSL_read`.

(All this is also covered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980911/1478356)

There have also been many reports of `SSL_read` returning `-1` (with `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` from `SSL_get_error`) when `errno = 0` (`WSAGetLastError` on windows) and the error queue being empty, when the underlying connection received an EOF.  See https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1903 for a long discussion; especially [this comment](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1903#issuecomment-262196212) explains how to manually check for EOF.

There have been claims this got fixed in 1.1.0d, but there were other reports with this error in 1.1.0f (e.g. https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2784).

Comment: Is there a general cause for SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, and a recommended solution?  That some of the documentation appears to be incorrect / out-of-date is not an optimistic indication ....

Comment: The general cause is an (unhandled) error of a "syscall", i.e. low-level POSIX ("libc") function. `errno` / `WSAGetLastError` should give you the underlying issue.