# What is premature close as for network programming?

Tags: c, sockets

I am reading [An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F02/Projects/lab01/reference/part1.pdf)  and here's code from *Figure 6*

```
while(1){
    r=SSL_read(ssl,buf,BUFSIZZ);
    switch(SSL_get_error(ssl,r)){
        case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
            len=r;
            break;
        case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
            goto shutdown;
        case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
            fprintf(stderr,
            "SSL Error: Premature close0");
            goto done;
        default:
            berr_exit("SSL read problem");
}
        fwrite(buf,1,len,stdout);
}
```

And underneath, in the *Error Handling* sections, it says:

> ### Error Handling
>
> If the return value was something negative then some
>   kind of error occurred. There are two kinds of errors we’re concerned
>   with: ordinary errors and "premature closes". We use the
>   `SSL_get_error()` call to determine which kind of error we have. Error
>   handling in our client is pretty primitive so with most errors we
>   simply call `berr_exit()` to print an error message and exit. **Premature
>   closes have to be handled specially**.

What is premature close? (I didn't find anything related on SO) Why here it's saying it need to be handled specially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of oversimplifying:

1. At the TCP/IP level, a TCP connection may be "closed gracefully" (both sides send a FIN to close their respective connections), or "terminated abruptly" (one side or another gets a RST). You can read more in [RFC 783](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt).
2. SSL introduces additional protocols on top of TCP/IP.
3. Older versions of SSL were vulnerable to "truncation attacks":

> https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F02/Projects/lab01/reference/part1.pdf
>
> TCP uses a FIN segment to indicate that the sender has sent all of its
>   data. SSL version 2 simply allowed either side to send a TCP FIN to
>   terminate the SSL connection. This allowed for a "truncation attack":
>   the attacker could make it appear that a message was shorter than it
>   was simply by forging a TCP FIN. Unless the victim had some other way
>   of knowing what message length to expect it would simply believe that
>   it had received a shorter message.

4. SSLv3 introduced a "close_notify alert" to mitigate this potential security problem:

> The *close_notify* is  an  SSL  message  (and  therefore  secured)  but 
>   is  not  part  of  the  data  stream  itself and so is not seen by the
>   application. No data may be transmitted after the close_notify is
>   sent.
>
> Thus, when *SSL_read()* returns 0 to indicate that the socket has
>   been closed, this really means  that  the *close_notify*  has  been 
>   received.  If  the  client  receives *FIN*  before  receiving 
>   a close_notify, *SSL_read()* will return with an error. This is called a
>   "premature close".

5. "Unfortunately", the article continues, "sending premature closes is a rather common error, particularly common with clients".  They should be handled "differently" from other errors.  Or perhaps sometimes even best ignored.

Here's another good link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28056464/421195

Comment: OK .Both terminated abruptly from clients or truncation attack would cause premature close, and now the best practice is to ignore premature errors because you can't tell whether it's an attack or a common error. Then what's the meaning of introducing the `close_notify` alert..? Kinda funny...